# Trying to insert taxonomy term from view into page title on Drupal 7 site

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a number of views on my website that use a taxonomy term as a contextual filter. I am trying to get that taxonomy term into the page title.

i.e.

```
'Latest TAXONOMY_TERM News | Sitename etc.'
```

I am using taxonomy_term_load in a THEME_views_post_render function in my template.php to fetch the term and build the page title. I am then passing this variable to the THEME_preprocess_html where I use it to override $variables['head_title'].

i.e.

views_post_render:

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($view->result[0]->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_term['und'][0]['tid']);

$page_title = 'Latest ' . $term->name . ' News | ' . variable_get('site_name', 'Sitename etc');
```

preprocess_html:

```
$variables['head_title'] = $page_title ;
```

If I echo out $variables['head_title'] I can see the page title I have defined in THEME_views_post_render but it is clearly missing the taxonomy term.

i.e.

```
'Latest News | Sitename etc.'
```

Can anyone throw any light on what's happening here? I did think about doing all the logic within the THEME_preprocess_html function, but this doesn't seem to have access to the view.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Rob.

Answer (score 0):

In view title you can use replacement pattern which will present term-name. using this you can set required page title.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide how you are computing/filling the $view variable in your code snippet. Make sure first that you are getting that right. I'll also suggest using [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module's [dpm](http://ratatosk.net/drupal/tutorials/debugging-drupal.html) functionality (or its friends) instead of using echo for your debugging.